# specify threads number in C Sharp

Tags: c#, multithreading, dynamic, macros

Is there a way to code threads dynamically in C#?
for example we want program user to define numbers of threads used for some calculation

Comment: I think the answer to this is yes but need more information before I show you an example.  Perhaps you could explain more about the requirement and the nature of the calculation in particular?

Comment: What kind of calculation is it? Not every algorithm can be parallelized, but if it can then you can create any reasonable number of threads easily. However, you won't benefit much from having 100 threads on a dual-core machine.

Comment: It doesn't matter because it is related to art of programming and i know that threading for algorithms that are sequential is waste of time(not it can't be and it is possible).assume that all operations are defined and it has relation between the numbers of threads and these operations functionallity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` when using `Parallel`. It may decide to use fewer threads, but it won't use more.

You can manually create x threads, and piece them out bits of work yourself.

You can break the work into smaller work-items yourself, enqueue them on the default thread-pool, and call `SetMaxThreads`.

Like above, but not interferring with other code, you can enqueue delegates onto your own thread-safe queue, and create x threads which dequeue and invoke until the queue is empty.

You can use a `Semaphore`.

Comment: You said using semaphore but i haven't common resource.please describe more if it has any other appliance.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your question, could you rephrase?

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad topic, but if your are using .NET 4.0 and are mostly CPU bound (which you indicate you are), then look into the [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd987541.aspx) class. By default it selects the number of threads used(*), but you can also [change that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx).

(*) Typically based on the number of CPUs / cores you have, which makes sense for CPU intensive operations.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ThreadPool

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(v=vs.80).aspx